# In wave equation, what is the meaning of poynting vector, compare to the amplitude vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, maxwell-equations, poynting-vector

I'm looking at this equation:

$$\tilde{\vec E}(\vec r,t)=\tilde{\vec E}_0e^{i(\vec k\cdot r-\omega t)}\hat n \tag{1}$$

I thought that $\tilde{\vec E}_0$ was the polarization vector, but then he added $\hat n$ which is supposed to be the polarization vector... So I don't understand, what is the meaning of the amplitude being a vector..?

Comment: There are too many vectors in that equation. Either $E_0$ should be a scalar, or $\mathbf{n}$ should not be there.

Comment: What does the tilde over the E vector represent?  A tilde over an arrow is not standard notation

Comment: Furthermore in the exponent the $r$ should be a vector too

Comment: That makes sense.. its equation from some guy on youtube so probably its his mistake..

Comment: The tilde is likely the notation that the letter it accents is a complex quantity as opposed to a real number. Griffiths uses this notation on his EM book.